Saving username and password data problem in ActionScript 2 class
I'm currently having trouble with trying to save username and password data in real time. When I created my username and password and pressed OK to start the process. I was expecting for the code to go the buildSignIn function, but it does not, instead keeps on going to the buildRegister function and actually DOES NOT save my username and password data at all, which my code here is very broken. I don't know why this happens.
class RedFire
{
    var _timeline;
    var remote;
    var dataManager;
    var _onButtonPress;
    var logo;
    var preloader;
    var progressBackground;
    var registerBackground;
    var strapA;
    var fadeIn;
    var fadeOut;
    var _pdsLoop;
    var _isFirstRun;
    var _isUsername;
    var _isPassword;
    var _updateFrame;
    var _checkPersistantDataState;
    var _start;
    var defaultIcon;
    var window;
    var _container;
    var _container2;
    var _container4;
    var _username;
    var usernameOutput;
    var _password;
    var _passwordInput;
    var passwordOutput;
    var _codeInput;
    var codeOutput;
    var codeOutputBackground;
    var timer;
    var _date;
    var imageLoader;
    var randomIndex;
    var backgroundPath;
    var backgroundLoader;
    var _onAButtonPress;
    var _onCheckLogin;
    var _onRetryPassword;
    var checkPassword;
    var generatedCode;
    var userInfo;
    var dispatchEvent;
    var onEnterFrame;
    static var _instance;
    static var PDM_GUID = "983813B47CA2B85EC5E26FBC1E876B29";
    static var NTLG_FONT = "nintendo_NTLG-DB_001";
    static var STRAP_A = "strapA";
    static var DATA_VERSION = 1;
    static var en = platform.nintendo.wii.Wii.LANG_ENGLISH;
    static var es = platform.nintendo.wii.Wii.LANG_SPANISH;
    static var fr = platform.nintendo.wii.Wii.LANG_FRENCH;
    static var it = platform.nintendo.wii.Wii.LANG_ITALIAN;
    static var de = platform.nintendo.wii.Wii.LANG_GERMAN;
    static var nl = platform.nintendo.wii.Wii.LANG_DUTCH;
    static var _isSoundInit = false;
    var _isInit = false;
    var _usernameSaved = false;
    var _passwordSaved = false;
    function RedFire()
    {
        super();
    }
    static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!RedFire._instance == null || RedFire._instance == undefined)
        {
            RedFire._instance = new RedFire();
        }
        return RedFire._instance;
    }
    function get timeline()
    {
        return this._timeline;
    }
    function init(timeline)
    {
        sugar.core.WiiSugarApplication.getInstance().initialize(timeline,null,platform.nintendo.wii.core.WiiApplication.STAGE_ALIGN_TOP_CENTER);
        this._timeline = timeline;
        this._onAButtonPress = mx.utils.Delegate.create(this, this.onAButtonPress);
        this._onCheckLogin = mx.utils.Delegate.create(this, this.onCheckLogin);
        this._onRetryPassword = mx.utils.Delegate.create(this, this.onRetryPassword);
        this.defaultIcon = _root.attachMovie("defaultProfileIcon", "defaultIcon", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        this.defaultIcon._visible = false;
        this.defaultIcon.enabled = false;
        platform.nintendo.wii.Wii.homeButtonEnabled = false;
        platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.getInstance(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.REMOTE_1).cursorVisible = false;
        platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.getInstance(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.REMOTE_1).cursorLocked = true;
        sugar.utils.UIShape.crop(this.defaultIcon,"circle",100,100);
        this.buildStrapA();
    }
    function buildStrapA()
    {
        this._onButtonPress = mx.utils.Delegate.create(this, this.onButtonPress);
        var language = platform.nintendo.wii.Wii.getLanguage();
        if ((language == RedFire.en))
        {
            this.strapA = _root.attachMovie(RedFire.STRAP_A + "_" + "en", "strapA", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        }
        else if ((language == RedFire.es))
        {
            this.strapA = _root.attachMovie(RedFire.STRAP_A + "_" + "es", "strapA", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        }
        else if ((language == RedFire.fr))
        {
            this.strapA = _root.attachMovie(RedFire.STRAP_A + "_" + "fr", "strapA", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        }
        else if ((language == RedFire.it))
        {
            this.strapA = _root.attachMovie(RedFire.STRAP_A + "_" + "it", "strapA", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        }
        else if ((language == RedFire.de))
        {
            this.strapA = _root.attachMovie(RedFire.STRAP_A + "_" + "de", "strapA", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        }
        else if ((language == RedFire.nl))
        {
            this.strapA = _root.attachMovie(RedFire.STRAP_A + "_" + "nl", "strapA", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        }
        this.fadeIn = _root.attachMovie("fadeInAnimation", "fadeIn", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        this.fadeIn._width = 854;
        this.fadeIn._height = 480;
        platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.getInstance(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.REMOTE_1).addEventListener(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerEvent.BUTTON_PRESS,RedFire.getInstance()._onButtonPress);
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
        this.destroyStrapA();
        },30000);
    }
    function onButtonPress(e)
    {
        var button = e.data.button;
        var validButtons = [platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerButton.CORE_A, platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerButton.CORE_B, platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerButton.CORE_1, platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerButton.CORE_2, platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerButton.CORE_PLUS, platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerButton.CORE_MINUS, platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerButton.NUNCHUCK_Z, platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerButton.NUNCHUCK_C, platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerButton.CORE_UP, platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerButton.CORE_DOWN, platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerButton.CORE_LEFT, platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerButton.CORE_RIGHT];
        if (validButtons.indexOf(button) >= 0)
        {
            this.destroyStrapA();
        }
    }
    function destroyStrapA()
    {
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
        platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.getInstance(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.REMOTE_1).removeEventListener(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerEvent.BUTTON_PRESS,RedFire.getInstance()._onButtonPress);
        _root.strapA.removeMovieClip();
        _root.fadeIn.removeMovieClip();
        _root.fadeOut.removeMovieClip();
        RedFire.getInstance().buildPreloader();
        },2000);
        this.fadeOut = _root.attachMovie("fadeOutAnimation", "fadeOut", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        this.fadeOut._width = 854;
        this.fadeOut._height = 480;
    }
    function buildPreloader()
    {
        this.logo = _root.attachMovie("logo", "logo", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        this.logo._x = 247.6;
        this.logo._y = 42.7;
        this.preloader = _root.attachMovie("preloader", "preloader", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        this.preloader._x = 344.7;
        this.preloader._y = 307.15;
        var totalBytes = 0;
        var loadedBytes = 0;
        _root.onEnterFrame = function()
        {
            if (_root.getBytesTotal() > 0)
            {
                totalBytes = _root.getBytesTotal();
                loadedBytes = _root.getBytesLoaded();
                var percentage = Math.floor((loadedBytes / totalBytes) * 100);
                if (percentage >= 100)
                {
                    percentage = 100;
                    RedFire.getInstance().loadData();
                    platform.nintendo.wii.Wii.homeButtonEnabled = true;
                    platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.getInstance(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.REMOTE_1).cursorVisible = true;
                    platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.getInstance(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.REMOTE_1).cursorLocked = false;
                    delete _root.onEnterFrame;
                }
                this.preloader._field.text = percentage + 1;
            }
        };
        this.onPreloaderAnimationStart();
    }
    function loadData()
    {
        this.dataManager = new sugar.data.PersistantDataManager();
        this.dataManager.loadSharedObject("RedFireData");
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            RedFire.getInstance().destroyPreloader();
        },13000);
    }
    function destroyPreloader()
    {
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
        _root.preloader.removeMovieClip();
        _root.logo.removeMovieClip();
        RedFire.getInstance().buildIntro();
        },5000);
        this.onPreloaderAnimationEnd();
    }
    function onPreloaderAnimationStart()
    {
        var _logo = new mx.transitions.Tween(this.logo, "_alpha", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeIn, 0, 100, 2, true);
        var _preloader = new mx.transitions.Tween(this.preloader, "_alpha", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeIn, 0, 100, 2, true);
    }
    function onPreloaderAnimationEnd()
    {
        var _logo = new mx.transitions.Tween(this.logo, "_alpha", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeIn, 100, 0, 2, true);
        var _preloader = new mx.transitions.Tween(this.preloader, "_alpha", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeIn, 100, 0, 2, true);
    }
    function buildIntro()
    {
        var savedUser = this.dataManager.getObjectValue("username");
        var savedPassword = this.dataManager.getObjectValue("password");
        if (savedUser && savedPassword)
        {
            this._usernameSaved = true;
            this._passwordSaved = true;
            this.buildSignIn();
        }
        else
        {
            this.buildRegister();
        }
    }
    function buildRegister()
    {
        this.registerBackground = _root.attachMovie("background", "registerBackground", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        this.window = new ui.Window();
        if (platform.nintendo.wii.Wii.getAspectRatio() == platform.nintendo.wii.Wii.ASPECT_RATIO_4X3)
        {
            this.window.buildWindow("windowBackground","exitButton","minimizeButton",107,27.65,720.2,28.35,658.2,27.65);
            this.window.buildTitle("Register",108.2,28.95,543.4,24.1,0xFFFFFF,RedFire.NTLG_FONT,18);
            this._container = _root.createTextField("textContainer", _root.getNextHighestDepth(), 132.6, 65.2, 597.8, 22.7);
            this._container2 = _root.createTextField("textContainer2", _root.getNextHighestDepth(), 132.6, 189.15, 597.8, 22.7);
            this._username = _root.attachMovie("input", "_username", _root.getNextHighestDepth(), {_x:132.6, _y:96.2});
            this._password = _root.attachMovie("input", "_password", _root.getNextHighestDepth(), {_x:132.6, _y:219.55});
        }
        else
        {
            this.window.buildWindow("windowBackground","exitButton","minimizeButton",70,27.65,747.5,28.35,685.5,27.65);
            this.window.buildTitle("Register",72.4,28.95,598.9,24.1,0xFFFFFF,RedFire.NTLG_FONT,18);
            this._container = _root.createTextField("textContainer", _root.getNextHighestDepth(), 132.6, 104.8, 628.35, 22.7);
            this._container2 = _root.createTextField("textContainer2", _root.getNextHighestDepth(), 132.6, 200.55, 628.35, 22.7);
            this._username = _root.attachMovie("input", "_username", _root.getNextHighestDepth(), {_x:132.6, _y:135.65});
            this._password = _root.attachMovie("input", "_password", _root.getNextHighestDepth(), {_x:132.6, _y:230.15});
        }
        this._start = _root.attachMovie("uiButtonSizeRectangle1", "_start", _root.getNextHighestDepth(), {_x:326, _y:321.75});
        this._start.enabled = false;
        this._start._visible = false;
        this._username._field.text = platform.nintendo.wii.Wii.getNickname();
        this._password._visible = true;
        this._username._visible = true;
        this._password._field.onChanged = function()
        {
            RedFire.getInstance().validatePassword();
        };
        var checkInterval = setInterval(function ()
        {
        if (ui.Keyboard.getInstance()._isDone == true)
        {
        clearInterval(checkInterval);
        }
        }, 100);
        var format = new TextFormat();
        format.font = RedFire.NTLG_FONT;
        format.size = 15;
        format.color = 0xFFFFFF;
        format.align = "left";
        this._container.text = "Please enter your name" + ":";
        this._container.setTextFormat(format);
        this._container.autoSize = true;
        this._container.selectable = false;
        this._container2.text = "Please enter your password" + ":";
        this._container2.setTextFormat(format);
        this._container2.autoSize = true;
        this._container2.selectable = false;
        this.window.disableWindowControls();
        this.window.hideWindowControls();
    }
    function validatePassword()
    {
        if (this._password._field.text.length > 8 && this._password._field.text.indexOf(" ") === -1)
        {
            this._start.enabled = true;
            this._start._visible = true;
            this._start._field.text = "OK";
            this._start.onRollOut = function()
            {
                var transform = new Color(this);
                var tint = {ra:60, rb:0, ga:60, gb:0, ba:60, bb:0};
                transform.setTransform(tint);
                platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.getInstance(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.REMOTE_1).startVibrate(50,200,3);
            };
            this._start.onRollOver = function()
            {
                trace("s");
                var transform = new Color(this);
                var tint = {ra:60, rb:102, ga:60, gb:0, ba:60, bb:0};
                transform.setTransform(tint);
                platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.getInstance(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.REMOTE_1).startVibrate(50,200,3);
            };
            this._start.onRelease = function()
            {
                this._field.text = "";
                var transform = new Color(this);
                var tint = {ra:60, rb:0, ga:60, gb:0, ba:60, bb:0};
                transform.setTransform(tint);
                platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.getInstance(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.REMOTE_1).startVibrate(50,200,3);
                RedFire.getInstance().saveUsernameAndPassword();
            };
        }
    }
    function saveUsernameAndPassword()
    {
        var self = this;
        this._start.enabled = false;
        this._start._visible = false;
        this.progressBackground = _root.createEmptyMovieClip("progressBackground", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        this.progressBackground.beginFill(0x000000,50);
        this.progressBackground.moveTo(0,0);
        this.progressBackground.lineTo(854,0);
        this.progressBackground.lineTo(854,480);
        this.progressBackground.lineTo(0,480);
        this.progressBackground.lineTo(0,0);
        this.progressBackground.endFill();
        this.progressBackground._x = 0;
        this.progressBackground._y = 0;
        var container = _root.createTextField("textContainer3", _root.getNextHighestDepth(), 161, 197.8, 558.9, 28.9);
        var format = new TextFormat();
        format.font = RedFire.NTLG_FONT;
        format.size = 15;
        format.color = 0xFFFFFF;
        format.align = "left";
        container.text = "Saving your username and password" + "." + "." + ".";
        container.setTextFormat(format);
        container.autoSize = true;
        container.selectable = false;
        this.usernameOutput = this._username._field.text;
        this.passwordOutput = this._password._field.text;
        if (this.usernameOutput.length > 0 && this.passwordOutput.length > 0)
        {
            this.dataManager.setObjectValue("username",this._username,true);
            this.dataManager.setObjectValue("password",this._password,true);
            this._usernameSaved = true;
            this._passwordSaved = true;
            setTimeout(function ()
            {
            _root.registerBackground.removeMovieClip();
            _root._start.removeMovieClip();
            _root.progressBackground.removeMovieClip();
            container.removeTextField();
            self.window.destroyWindow();
            RedFire.getInstance().destroyRegister();
            RedFire.getInstance().buildPreloader();
            RedFire.getInstance().hideUserInfo();
            },15000);
        }
    }
    function destroyRegister()
    {
        this._container.removeTextField();
        this._container2.removeTextField();
    }
    function hideUserInfo()
    {
        _root._username._visible = false;
        _root._password._visible = false;
    }
    function buildSignIn()
    {
        this.onSignInAnimationStart();
        this.loadBackgroundInSequence();
        this.timer = _root.createTextField("timerContainer", _root.getNextHighestDepth(), 365.55, 112, 131.35, 53.8);
        this._date = _root.createTextField("dateContainer", _root.getNextHighestDepth(), 255.4, 167.75, 359, 23.95);
        var format = new TextFormat();
        format.font = RedFire.NTLG_FONT;
        format.size = 40;
        format.color = 0xFFFFFF;
        format.align = "center";
        var dateFormat = new TextFormat();
        dateFormat.font = RedFire.NTLG_FONT;
        dateFormat.size = 16;
        dateFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF;
        dateFormat.align = "center";
        this.timer.text = sugar.utils.DateManager.getTime();
        this.timer.setTextFormat(format);
        this.timer.autoSize = true;
        this.timer.selectable = false;
        this._date.text = sugar.utils.DateManager.getDate();
        this._date.setTextFormat(dateFormat);
        this._date.selectable = false;
        platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.getInstance(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.REMOTE_1).addEventListener(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerEvent.BUTTON_PRESS,RedFire.getInstance()._onAButtonPress);
    }
    function loadBackgroundInSequence()
    {
        this.imageLoader = _root.createEmptyMovieClip("imageLoader", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        this.randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19);
        this.backgroundPath = "images/background" + this.randomIndex + ".jpg";
        this.backgroundLoader = this.imageLoader.attachMovie("imageLoader", "backgroundLoader", this.imageLoader.getNextHighestDepth());
        this.imageLoader.backgroundLoader.loadMovie(backgroundPath);
        this.imageLoader.backgroundLoader.onLoadInit = function(success)
        {
            if (success)
            {
                this._width = 854;
                this._height = 480;
            }
        };
    }
    function onSignInAnimationStart()
    {
        var _imageLoader = new mx.transitions.Tween(this.imageLoader, "_alpha", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeIn, 0, 100, 2, true);
        this.fadeIn = _root.attachMovie("fadeInAnimation", "fadeIn", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        this.fadeIn._width = 854;
        this.fadeIn._height = 480;
    }
    function onSignInAnimationMiddleEnd()
    {
        var dateTween = new mx.transitions.Tween(this._date, "_y", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeIn, this._date._y, -53.05, 1, true);
        var timerTween = new mx.transitions.Tween(this.timer, "_y", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeIn, this.timer._y, -108.8, 1, true);
    }
    function onSignIn()
    {
        this.defaultIcon._visible = true;
        this.defaultIcon.enabled = true;
        this.defaultIcon._x = 374.05;
        this.defaultIcon._y = 88;
        this._passwordInput = _root.attachMovie("passwordInput", "_passwordInput", _root.getNextHighestDepth(), {_x:273.95, _y:210.05});
        sugar.utils.UIShape.crop(this.defaultIcon,"circle",100,100);
        platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.getInstance(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.REMOTE_1).addEventListener(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerEvent.BUTTON_PRESS,RedFire.getInstance()._onCheckLogin);
    }
    function onAButtonPress(e)
    {
        if (e.data.button == platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerButton.CORE_A)
        {
            this.onSignInAnimationMiddleEnd();
            setTimeout(function ()
            {
            RedFire.getInstance().onSignIn();
            },2000);
        }
    }
    function onCheckLogin(e)
    {
        this._passwordInput._visible = false;
        this._passwordInput.enabled = false;
        if (e.data.button == platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerButton.CORE_A)
        {
            if (this._passwordInput._field.text == this._password)
            {
                this.destroySignIn();
            }
            else
            {
                var container = _root.createTextField("textContainer3", _root.getNextHighestDepth(), 161, 197.8, 558.9, 28.9);
                var format = new TextFormat();
                format.font = RedFire.NTLG_FONT;
                format.size = 20;
                format.color = 0xFFFFFF;
                format.align = "center";
                container.text = "Your password is incorrect. Please try again.";
                container.setTextFormat(format);
                container.selectable = false;
                platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.getInstance(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiRemote.REMOTE_1).addEventListener(platform.nintendo.wii.WiiControllerEvent.BUTTON_PRESS,RedFire.getInstance()._onRetryPassword);
            }
        }
    }
    function destroySignIn()
    {
        this.timer._visible = false;
        this.timer.enabled = false;
        this._date._visible = false;
        this._date.enabled = false;
        this.imageLoader.removeMovieClip();
    }
    function onRetryPassword()
    {
        this._passwordInput._visible = true;
        this._passwordInput.enabled = true;
    }
    function get isFirstRun()
    {
        return this._isFirstRun;
    }
    function set isFirstRun(value)
    {
        this._isFirstRun = value;
        this.dataManager.setObjectValue("firstRun",this._isFirstRun,true);
    }
    function get isUsername()
    {
        return this._isUsername;
    }
    function set isUsername(value)
    {
        this._isUsername = value;
        this.dataManager.setObjectValue("username",this._isUsername,true);
    }
    function get isPassword()
    {
        return this._isPassword;
    }
    function set isPassword(value)
    {
        this._isPassword = value;
        this.dataManager.setObjectValue("password",this._isPassword,true);
    }
    function loadPersistentData()
    {
        this.dataManager.loadSharedObject(RedFire.PDM_GUID);
        this._checkPersistantDataState = mx.utils.Delegate.create(this, this.checkPersistantDataState);
        if (!this._pdsLoop)
        {
            this._pdsLoop = this.timeline.createEmptyMovieClip("PDS_Temp_Loop", this.timeline.getNextHighestDepth());
        }
        this._pdsLoop.onEnterFrame = this._checkPersistantDataState;
    }
    function get isInit()
    {
        return this._isInit;
    }
    function checkPersistantDataState(pEvent)
    {
        this._updateFrame = this._updateFrame + 1;
        if (this._updateFrame < 15 || this.isInit)
        {
            return undefined;
        }
        if (this._updateFrame > 900)
        {
            this.pdsOnLoadError();
            return undefined;
        }
        this.dataManager.getDataSize();
        if (this.dataManager.getDataSize() == 0)
        {
            this.createDefaultPersistentData();
            this.pdsOnLoadComplete();
        }
        else if (this.dataManager.isDataValid())
        {
            if (this.dataManager.getObjectValue("dataVersion") == RedFire.DATA_VERSION)
            {
                this.pdsOnLoadComplete();
            }
            else
            {
                this.createDefaultPersistentData();
                this.pdsOnLoadComplete();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.pdsOnLoadError();
        }
    }
    function createDefaultPersistentData()
    {
        this._isFirstRun = true;
        this._isUsername = true;
        this._isPassword = true;
        this.dataManager.setObjectValue("firstRun",this._isFirstRun,true);
        this.dataManager.setObjectValue("username",this.usernameOutput,true);
        this.dataManager.setObjectValue("password",this.passwordOutput,true);
        this.dataManager.saveData();
    }
    function parseGameSaveData()
    {
        var _firstRun = Boolean(this.dataManager.getObjectValue("firstRun"));
        var _username = Boolean(this.dataManager.getObjectValue("username"));
        var _password = Boolean(this.dataManager.getObjectValue("password"));
        this.isFirstRun = _firstRun;
        this.isUsername = _username;
        this.isPassword = _password;
        this.dataManager.saveData();
        this.completeDataLoading();
    }
    function completeDataLoading()
    {
        if (this._pdsLoop)
        {
            this._pdsLoop.removeMovieClip();
        }
        this._pdsLoop = null;
        this.dispatchEvent(new data.DataEvent(data.DataEvent.COMPLETE, this, null));
    }
    function pdsOnLoadComplete()
    {
        this._pdsLoop.onEnterFrame = null;
        this._pdsLoop.removeMovieClip();
        this.dispatchEvent(new data.DataEvent(data.DataEvent.PERISITENT_DATA_LOADED, this, null));
    }
    function pdsOnLoadError()
    {
        this._pdsLoop.onEnterFrame = null;
        this._pdsLoop.removeMovieClip();
        this.dispatchEvent(new data.DataEvent(data.DataEvent.PERISITENT_DATA_FAILED, this, null));
        this.dispatchEvent(new data.DataEvent(data.DataEvent.ERROR, this));
    }
}

class sugar.data.PersistantDataManager
{
    var _so;
    var _delayWrite;
    var _status = "";
    var _frame = 0;
    var _delay = 0;
    var _cachedWrite = false;
    function PersistentDataManager()
    {
        this._so = null;
    }
    function loadSharedObject(pSharedObjectID)
    {
        this._so = SharedObject.getLocal(pSharedObjectID,"/");
        this._so.onStatus = mx.utils.Delegate.create(this,this.onStatusUpdate);
        if(this._so == null)
        {
        }
    }
    function onStatusUpdate(pStatusInfo)
    {
        this._status = pStatusInfo.code;
        switch(this._status)
        {
            case "SharedObject.Flush.Failed":
            return undefined;
            case "SharedObject.Flush.Success":
            return undefined;
            default:
        }
    }
    function onDelay()
    {
        if(this._frame > this._delay)
        {
            this._delay = 0;
            this._frame = 0;
            delete this._delayWrite.onEnterFrame;
            if(this._cachedWrite)
            {
                this._cachedWrite = false;
                this.saveData();
            }
        }
        this._frame = this._frame + 1;
    }
    function saveData()
    {
        if(!this._delayWrite)
        {
            this._delayWrite = _root.createEmptyMovieClip("PDM_DELAY_WRITE_MC",_root.getNextHighestDepth());
        }
        if(this._so != null)
        {
            if(this._delay)
            {
                this._delay = 5;
                this._cachedWrite = true;
                return true;
            }
            if(this._delayWrite.onEnterFrame == null)
            {
                this._delay = 3;
                this._delayWrite.onEnterFrame = mx.utils.Delegate.create(this,this.onDelay);
            }
            this._so.data.__soChecksum = this.hashData();
            this._so.flush();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    function clearData()
    {
        if(this._so != null)
        {
            this._so.clear();
        }
    }
    function getDataSize()
    {
        if(this._so != null)
        {
            return this._so.getSize();
        }
        return -1;
    }
    function getLastStatus()
    {
        if(this._so != null)
        {
            return this._status;
        }
        return "";
    }
    function isDataValid()
    {
        if(this._so == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        var _hashData = this.hashData();
        return Boolean(_hashData == this._so.data.__soChecksum);
    }
    function setObjectValue(pObjectName, pObjectValue, pSave)
    {
        if(this.currentData != null)
        {
            this.currentData[pObjectName] = pObjectValue;
            if(pObjectValue == null)
            {
                delete this.currentData[pObjectName];
            }
            if(pSave == true)
            {
                this.saveData();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    function getObjectValue(pObjectName)
    {
        if(this.currentData != null)
        {
            return this.currentData[pObjectName];
        }
        return null;
    }
    function getCurrentData()
    {
        if(this._so != null)
        {
            return this._so.data;
        }
        return null;
    }
    function set currentData(pData)
    {
        if(this._so != null)
        {
            this._so.data = pData;
        }
    }
    function hashData()
    {
        var query = "hash=";
        if(this._so != null)
        {
            query += this.stringify(this._so.data);
        }
        return sugar.utils.MD5.calculate(query);
    }
    function stringify(obj)
    {
        switch(typeof obj)
        {
            case "string":
            case "number":
            case "boolean":
            return obj.toString();
            case "object":
            var placeholder = "";
            if(obj instanceof Array)
            {
                placeholder = "Array[";
                var placeholder2 = 0;
                while(placeholder2 < obj.length)
                {
                    placeholder += this.stringify(obj[placeholder2]) + (placeholder2 != obj.length - 1 ? "," : "");
                    placeholder2 = placeholder2 + 1;
                }
                placeholder += "]";
                return placeholder;
            }
            placeholder = "Object[";
            var placeholder3 = [];
            var placeholder4 = undefined;
            for(placeholder4 in obj)
            {
                if(placeholder4 != "__soChecksum")
                {
                    placeholder3.push(placeholder4);
                }
            }
            placeholder3.sort();
            placeholder2 = placeholder3.length - 1;
            while(placeholder2 >= 0)
            {
                placeholder += placeholder3[placeholder2] + ":" + this.stringify(this._so.data[placeholder3[placeholder2]]) + (placeholder2 != 0 ? "," : "");
                placeholder2 = placeholder2 - 1;
            }
            placeholder += "]";
            return placeholder;
            break;
          default:
          return "unknown{" + obj.toString() + "}";
        }
    }
}

I tried using the setObject or getObject data or one of these createDefaultPersistentData and parseGameSaveData and added them in my init function, but it does not work either, simple.

First: the provided code sample is overly huge, complicated and difficult to read. While asking questions you should strive to adhere to MCVE principles: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Second: I tracked the logic flow and I think the problem is this function getCurrentData() which should actually be a getter: function get currentData(). This small error must prevent you from reading any saved data so your code always act as if there is no saved data at any time.

The saving data actually works, ONLY, and I mean ONLY, when you have the app running. But if you exit the app, you no longer have your save data saved anymore

Nevermind, I fixed it.
